# UILabel with Rich Text HTML capability and Auto Layout support

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, richtext

I'm searching for a way to display styled text in an UILabel. There are different ways to manage that:

- Using a UIWebView
- [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)
- [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel)
- [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText)

However it seems that those possibilities do not support auto layout in the way UILabel does:

If I'm using a constraint with the visual format `V:|[styledLabel]` and `H:|[styledLabel]` (no absolute height or width is set), the label subclass (e.g. RTLabel) is not shown. If a height and a width is set, everything works fine.

Is there any way to manage styled text with using the constraints above?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you got any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue of the label not showing while using OHAttributedLabel and auto layout. I just tried TTTAttributedLabel (https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) and it seems to work. Will have to test more to be sure everything is working fine...just a heads up if you would like to check it out as well (and are still in need of this) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use attributed strings and UILabel, which became possible at the same time Autolayout did (iOS6). If you need to convert HTML into attributed strings, try something like [this](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText).